# Connect to an NAS server directly

Tags: nas

I have got a Thecus [NAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) server and I am trying to connect it directly to a linux machine. There are two network cards on this machine:

```
sudo ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:30:5b:b9:38:bd  
          inet addr:12.97.33.70  Bcast:12.97.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::be30:5bff:feb9:38bd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6454 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4019 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2702341 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:689534 (689.5 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:10:18:8a:b8:c0  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:56 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1060 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1060 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:126169 (126.1 KB)  TX bytes:126169 (126.1 KB)
```

I have set the ip address, net mask and gateway of the second netword card (eth1) by doing:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.101 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 eth1

route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Now I am supposed to be able to reach the NAS server through

```
http://192.168.1.100
```

but I can't, the browser says webpage not available, what's worse, I lost my internet connection on eth0 instantly after executing these commands.

Result of `ip link`:

```
ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:30:5b:b9:38:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:18:8a:b8:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you `ping 192.168.1.100`? The reason you lost Internet access is that you changed the default gateway to `192.168.1.1` (whatever that device is), whereas your Internet traffic should be going out of `eth0` (assuming that it's your normal Internet route).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No, host unreachable.

Comment: ok. It looks like eth1 is down. Please see my edit to the question.

Comment: Try `# ip link set eth1 up` to bring `eth1` up. It shows `NO-CARRIER` though. Is the cable connected?

Comment: Just tried that and eth1 is still down. I will go to the server room and check if the cable is properly connected. Thanks.

Comment: The cable is indeed not plugged in, now I can reach the server. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant - now restore your default route to the original (Internet) and you'll be good to go.